# Finding whether an object of a list is present in another List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have two lists `List<AreaOfInterest>` and `List<AreaOfInterestBean>`. The corresponding classes are,

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table( name = "interest_area" )
public class AreaOfInterest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Column( name = "ia_id" )
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "ia_value" )
    private String value;

    @Column( name = "ia_is_active" )
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column( name = "ia_created_at" )
    private Calendar createdAt;

    @Column( name = "ia_is_approved" )
    private Boolean isApprovedByAdmin;

    @Column( name = "ia_approved_at" )
    private Calendar approvedAt;

}
```

and,

```
@Data
public class AreaOfInterestBean {

    private Long id;

    private String value;

    private boolean isSelected;
}
```

I want to check if the object of `List<AreaOfInterest>` is present in `List<AreaOfInterestBean>` and if so, I need to update the corresponding Object of `List<AreaOfInterestBean>`. Right now, I feel I have to iterate both lists to solve this problem. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: what is the equality between `AreaOfInterest` and `AreaOfInterestBean`?

Comment: @Eugene the field `value`

Comment: You want to check if each element in one list is in another list? And your goal is to do it more efficiently than iterating over both lists? Not without storing the data in another data structure like a hash set.

Comment: @nhouser9 that would require overriding equals/hashCode, not always an option...

Comment: You can indeed avoid O(N²) complexity. An example: turn your `List<AreaOfInterestBean>` into a `HashSet` of `id`s , then iterate over `List<AreaOfInterest>` to find occurrences in the set. You still iterate over both lists, but not nested, so complexity falls to O(N)

Comment: I assume that if `value` is the same (and unique) you simply want to update `isSelected`?

Comment: @Eugene Yes, that is exactly I want to do

Comment: do you want to update it with a plain `true` or the value that comes from `AreaOfInterest.isSelected`?

Comment: @Eugene Plain `true` will suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure of the complexity of this (I'll try to figure it out tomorrow):

```
Set<String> left = nonBeans.stream()
            .map(AreaOfInterest::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

beans.stream()
      .filter(x -> left.contains(x.getValue()))
      .forEach(x -> x.setSelected(true));
```

In this case the complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you. I will also try to figure out the complexity

Comment: Well, this is generally *O(n)*, as Joel pointed out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793392/finding-whether-an-object-of-a-list-is-present-in-another-list#comment90544455_51793392) (`HashSet.contains` has [*O(1)* average and *O(n)* worst-case complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski right, thank you! better then doing `O(n^2)`

Comment: @Eugene Definitely! You might also want to update the answer with the complexity info so that I could upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
List<AreaOfInterest> list = /* ... */
List<AreaOfInterestBean> listOfBeans = /* ... */
```

Two simple iterations would achieve it easily:

```
for (int i=0; i<listOfBeans.size(); i++) {                // Iterate beans
    AreaOfInterestBean aoiBean = listOfBeans.get(i);      // Get each bean
    for (int j=0; j<list.size(); j++) {                   // Iterate entity
        AreaOfInterest aoi = list.get(j);                 // Get each entity
        if (aoiBean.getId() == aoi.getId()) {             // If they have the same ID
            aoiBean.setValue(aoi.getValue());             // Update the bean value
            break;                                        // Go to the next bean
        }
    }
}
```

Example: Having the following simplified data:

- `AreaOfInterest` with `id` and `value`: `1, "Car"`, `2, "Bike"`, `3, "Ship"`
- `AreaOfInterestBeans` with `id` and `value`: `5, "Limo"`, `2, "Scooter"`, `7, "Yacht"`

The result `AreaOfInterestBeans` will be with replaced value of id `2`: `Scooter` -> `Bike`.

- `AreaOfInterestBeans` with `id` and `value`: `5, "Limo"`, `2, "Bike"`, `7, "Yacht"`

---

An alternative Stream way:

```
listOfBeans = listOfBeans.stream()
                  .peek(aoiBean -> list.stream()
                                       .filter(aoi -> aoi.getId() == aoiBean.getId())
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .ifPresent(i -> aoiBean.setValue(i.getValue())))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: of course yes. But I am looking for a better approach, which do not involve two for loops. Basically to reduce the complexity of `O(n^2) `. Thank you

Comment: This is complexity `O(n^2)` - two full iterations always result in this complexity.

Comment: @Nikolas You mean "two nested iterations", right? Two independent iterations would still be *O(n)*.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski: Yes, that's what I mean - an iteration in another one. If these are independent, the complexity would be `O(2n)` which is `O(n)`. "Nested" is the right word.

Comment: @Nikolas or simpler `leftList.size * rightList.size` vs `leftList.size + rightList.size`...